# Circleci build fails due to Unexpected token

Tags: webpack, jhipster, circleci

I new to Jipster and CircleCi
I'm trying to do ci for my project but my build fails with the following error :

> node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.prod.js" "--profile"

```
    /home/circleci/repo/webpack/webpack.common.js:14
                ...rxPaths()
                ^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
        at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/circleci/repo/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c
```

the code throwing the exception:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
        app: utils.root('src/main/webapp/app/'),
        ...rxPaths()(this is line 14)
    }
}
```

the config.yml lines where I install the node

```
            # Install Node for JH Build
        - run:
              name: Download Node
              command: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash
        - run:
              name: Install Node
              command: sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
        - run:
              name: update-npm
              command: sudo npm install -g npm@latest

        # Install Yarn
        - run:
              name: Download Yarn
              command: curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
        - run:
              name: Install Yarn
              command: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

I install the node every time the build runs.
I Use JHipster v5.4.1

edit: I added the config.yml

Comment: Well it is obvious that it does not understand ES6 spread. I already forgot if you need to ensure that your CirclyCI runs one of the latest Node versions or you need to install a special NPM module to make it work.

Comment: @anvk I install the NPM in the image I build

Comment: What Node version are you running in the image? Also if you really need it working just re-write your javascript as ES5 without spread for now and then try to figure out on how to support ES6 in your image. My bet is that your Node version is pretty old. You can always check it by running `node --version`

Comment: I was using an old version, after upgrading to the new one it worked.
thanks!

Comment: Not really seeking for points or anything but you should mark something as an answer here so that other people who have similar issue would know where to look for instead of seeing this question as an unanswered one. But again up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @anvk suggested the problem was in the node version.
I upgraded the version to 10 and it worked.